Upload file to S3 through AWS API Gateway REST API using serverless.yml
Is there any way to create AWS Api gateway REST API to create an endpoint and add a trigger to upload the file to S3 using serverless.yml template without using AWS lambda. I have gone through the documentation of serverless framework but not able to find any approach without using lambda.
